# ASP.net MVC3 Webgrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, webgrid

I am using a webgrid to display some dynamic data. I have recently refactored my code, to move away from a hierarchal Model, containing various different types of data to be displayed in a View to using ViewBag.

Previously the grid would sort the columns fine, just be clicking on the header, however since I changed to ViewBag, my table does not sort.  My new code is as follows:

```
@if (ViewBag.data != null)
{
var grid = new WebGrid(
    source: ViewBag.data,
    defaultSort: "StudyName",
    rowsPerPage: 10,
    canSort: true,
    canPage: true,
    ajaxUpdateContainerId: "tableDiv"
    ); 

@grid.GetHtml(
tableStyle: "resultTable",
columns: grid.Columns(
    ViewBag.columns)
)
}
```

Anybody any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have set the `CanSort` property to `true` on your `ViewBag.columns`:

```
ViewBag.columns = new[] 
{
    new WebGridColumn
    {
        ColumnName = "Id"
    },
    new WebGridColumn
    {
        CanSort = true,
        ColumnName = "StudyName"                
    },
};
```

Only columns that have this property set will appear as hyperlinks in the grid header allowing the user to sort on them.

Comment: Ha....I just came on here to say that I had figured it out using this method.  Thanks :)